# How to get a html5 canvas bigger than 311 by 211 in Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha Simulator

Tags: html, qt, canvas, webview, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to display graphs in html5 canvas in Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha Simulator running in VMWare, using C++ QT QML Blackberry 10 Cascades Beta 3 in a qml WebView.  I was having issues making that happen, but I tried the html5 sample from: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_first, which is the following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and then after some testing that that red square only showed up if I kept the width no more than 311 and the height no more than 211.  But I need to make my graphical content in the html5 canvas in my webview larger than that.  Does anyone know any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Obvious question, but are you sure you're re-sizing the `canvas` as well as the rectangle drawn onto it?

Comment: I'm just testing with say <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200" ... and keeping the rest of the code the same and nothing shows up (it doesn't matter what I put in between the canvas tags), it only shows up if the width and height attribute are less than 312 and 212 respectively).

Comment: I'd try to help you more, but I don't have any of that software. Sorry :(

Comment: I'm thinking it is a memory allocation error where it's not allocating space for the canvas when you try to allocate above a certain size, but I am not sure and I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Could be. Try on their forums or something where people probably already have the apps needed installed?